# Get number of rules in Geoserver style using webservice

Tags: geoserver, style

How can I know the default style for a layer in Geoserver, and the number of rules it contains, using a REST call or service?

Answer (score 1):

You can request the style using REST (_http://myserver.com/geoserver/styles/mystyle). Once you've got the file use something like

```
grep '<Rule' mystyle.sld | wc -l
```

to count the number of lines.

Obviously you can use any programming language of your choice to automate this.